# How can I pass an array to a Visualforce component, then use it in a repeat?

Tags: visualforce

I have code much like the following:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="fields" type="String[]" />
    <apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var="field">
        console.log('{!field}');
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

When this is placed in a page like this:

```
<c:MyCustomComponent fields="A,B,C">
```

The output is just **A,B,C** (a single value).  Enclosing the field names with square brackets does not help, nor does using single quotes.  Is there a way to pass an array into a component so that apex:repeat will work on it?  (I am aware that this could be done through the controller;  I am hoping for a solution that preserves the component interface).

Comment: try StringToStringMap construct `{!['herp'='derp', 'foo'='bar]}`

Comment: I've expanded upon @bigassforce suggestion by creating an answer in itself. I think that solution actually solves your question better than going the controller route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen any notation for parameter literal values in VisualForce that can convert to anything but a String, Number, Boolean, or (in this case) a 1-element array. I'd be very (pleasantly) surprised if you could do what you want. You'll need to populate the component attribute using a controller field reference.

Comment: Your observation that there is no literal notation for arrays in Visualforce is the insight I needed.  I'll have to go with the controller approach I guess.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a controller for the component itself.

You can pass the array in as a string, as you're doing and use the `assingTo` attribute on the component's parameter to pass the value to a property on the controller.

Then just have another method on the controller which returns the list:

```
public String theValueFromSomewhere {get; set;}

public List<String> GetBits()
{
  return theValueFromSomewhere.split(',');
}
```

You can then use `<apex:repeat value="{!Bits}" var="v">` in your component body as you're after.

Comment: Controller is best way. Option two is StringToStringMap {!['herp'='derp,'foo'='bar']}

Answer (score 3):

Just to be complete, by @mattandneil's suggestion, we *can* use literal expressions directly in Visualforce to achieve what we want. Visualforce supports the literal notation for maps like this:

```
<c:MyCustomComponent fields="{!['A'='','B'='','C'='']}">
```

I know, that looks like a `Map`, and we needed a `List`, right? Well, yes, but oddly this `Map` syntax actually only works for `List` parameters. It's sort of a bug in Salesforce, but it works in this case.

So to get it straight: in the case that a component parameter is of type `List`, then we can use a literal notation `Map` where only the keys of the provided map are taken into account and passed into the `List` parameter.

In this example that means that the key elements A,B and C will be used to populate the `String[]` `fields` parameter in the component. The value parts of the `Map` are ignored, that's why I usually fill them with just a blank value.